# Javascript to Enter Password Comes back blank

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a little project that uses Javascript to login to a local server GUI page for display on a department wallboard/TV. I'm attempting to automate this process using a Chrome bookmark with javascript embedded in the Bookmark URL.

If I login to the site manually while running Wireshark I can see the following on the first POST method that appears and I'm successfully authenticated. See the bottom of screenshot:
[image]

The Username portion is already prefilled in since the Username box is a dropdown box and the default user is the one we want... So for the Javascript, I should only need to input the password and then submit the form.

But, when I run the Bookmark containing the following Code below, it acts as though the textbox is empty... I know I've seen similar things on certain sites. Where your login info gets auto-filled. But you need to manually click into the password field and enter a character and then delete it before it recognizes you entered any text. Same thing appears to happen here.

```
let passwordBox = document.querySelector("input[type='password']");
passwordBox.value = "myPassword";
console.log(passwordBox.value);
document.getElementById('loginButton').click();
console.log("Button clicked");
```

**Here's what Wireshark shows when using the Javascript above:**
[image]

I even did an attempt where I removed the button click from the js, and then after the password was entered, I clicked into the textbox, added a space, and backspaced it, and the Hide/Show password button magically appeared, and clicking the Login button was successful.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Comment: Try `passwordBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))` after setting the value.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, that worked!!!

Comment: Glad that helped. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger an input event after setting the value.

```js
passwordBox.value = '...';
passwordBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```